# ImageMagickで、複数の「-draw "rectangle"」を一度に実行するには？

Tags: php, imagemagick

ImageMagickで、複数の下記画像加工コマンドを一度にまとめて実行するにはどうすればよいですか？

```
$convert1 = 'convert orig.jpg -fill "blue" -draw "rectangle 0,0 10,25" tmp1.jpg';
shell_exec($convert1);

$convert2 = 'convert tmp1.jpg -fill "red" -draw "rectangle 0,90 10,10" tmp2.jpg';
shell_exec($convert2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのまま繋げるとよいかと思います。

```bash
convert orig.jpg -fill "blue" -draw "rectangle 0,0 10,25" -fill "red" -draw "rectangle 0,90 10,10" tmp2.jpg
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。